# How can I decrypt data created by npm-rsa in PHP?

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, cryptography, phpseclib

I am encrypting data in the browser with JS, and then attempting to decrypt it on the backend with PHP.

In JS, I am using npm-rsa which was built using browserify.
In PHP, I am using phpseclib

My JS:

```
key = new rsa({
            environment: 'browser',
            encryptionScheme: 'pkcs1_oaep',
            signingScheme: 'pkcs1-sha256',
            b: 2048
        });

cleartext = 'this is a test';
console.log(key.encrypt(cleartext, 'base64'));
console.log(this.key.exportKey('pkcs8-private-pem'));
```

I then take my public key and cyphertext to PHP:

```
$rsa = new RSA();
$rsa->load($privkey, 'pkcs8');
$cleartext = $rsa->decrypt(base64_decode($cyphertext));
```

When I run this, `$cleartext` is `null`. Using Xdebug, I can see that `$rsa->load($pubkey, 'pkcs8');` does appear to be populating the modulus, exponents, primes, coefficients, etc fields of `$rsa`.

I have even tried `$rsa->setHash('sha256');` before calling `decrypt()`, but it's my understanding that the hash method is only used for encryption and not even used in decryption.

Also, I understand that this is not secure because i'm sharing the private key. I'm just trying to verify compatibility between the two libraries.

I have tested that i can encrypt and decrypt with both libraries independently, but taking a key from the JS lib to the PHP lib I can't get to work.

EDIT:
Exported private key:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

cyphertext:

```
mbPLBF3YNmyb5AD1vk6D8K0C9AiRU3C2a2aCKXpzDXb1uUCy7KYUFB3bOoU4ZhU7RXcWr9VHZq3APxtdyqKyEqr48NqVEPeBuYsDjcgDfPBFdPXf36f1FveeCJ7cFtHIvGy9/2EHIyNyXKy/6VaoakGRwBB3V14shXdqCDIW2FfEdUcfka5X8sAroq9pKrTGbN21hwtbiAjP2MmTHDYWu1zhDmrKxdcBbP6wdBgnZodCwGhBw11uXoEAnL1/yYFFqGZeKAhzxfjdPY2irvAuQOPN3U7UDBF0zhyMNF07JbCccCsNIguX4esferShw8w1mVzAxgwHzbjDpudko1/VSg==
```

I saved these into two files, privatekey.pem and cypher.text. Then I base64 decoded the cyphertext:

```
cat cypher.text | base64 --decode > -in cypher.bin
```

And use openssl to decrypt this:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey privatekey.pem -in cypher.bin -oaep
```

This gives me the cleartext! So it appears that phpseclib has an issue in decoding.

Comment: Do you know in what order the RSA and base64 works? If your javascript first encodes with base64 and then encrypts, your PHP is doing it the other way around and the decoding / decrypting will return `null` because it can't work with the format provided.

Comment: The JS version i believe encrypts, then base64 encodes. The resulting output is base64 for sure. Then in PHP, the function normally takes a byte string input, so i base64 decode it manually before putting it in to the decrypt method. I have tried in both libraries to verify that these are the formats they are inputing and outputting.

Comment: Alrighty (you might want to edit this into your question), have you verified the sending of the cyphertext goes well, as in... is `$cyphertext` set? (sorry for asking). Also, verify if the cyphertext before the encoding is equal to the cyphertext after decoding.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as the description doesn't match the source code. `$rsa->load($pubkey, 'pkcs8');` is nowhere to be found in the code, and without the required parts it is impossible to find the error.

Comment: @Glubus yes, in fact I'm not even sending it at this point. I'm dumping it to the console and explicitly assigning it to the variable in a test php script. i can put sample data here if that helps, including the cyphertext that's created by npm-rsa, that can be decrypted by npm-rsa but not by phpseclib. I didn't think that would be useful because it's just a lot of base64 encoded binary data

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - i'm not sure what you mean. do you mean that i'm not showing the code for the `load()` function? That is part of the phpseclib that i mentioned. You can find it's definition here: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Crypt/RSA.php#L685

Comment: With the sample values the question should already be much clearer. I mean that you said: "$rsa->load($pubkey, 'pkcs8'); does appear to be populating the modulus and exponent fields of $rsa" but I don't see how this relates to the code that shows the private key being used.

Comment: the private key includes the modulus, exponent for the public key and about 6 other long numbers. they are all populated. i verified this a few times. i even tried re-exporting the private key from the $rsa object and it came back out identical to how it went in, rebuilt from the populated numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the hash has to be set in the decryption method with BOTH:

```
$rsa->setMGFHash('sha1');
$rsa->setHash('sha1');
```

Although i had tried it with `setHash()`, it was not enough without also `setMGFHash()`